# itHit Ajax File Browser Customization

Tags: ithit-ajax-file-browser

I’m trying to hide certain buttons on the toolbar similar to the example on the site (http://www.ajaxfilebrowser.com/ITHitService/Toolbar.html?UserFolder=/User5d14282). However, when I use the example code, there’s an entire set of buttons that show up for me – cut, copy, paste, a globe, etc.

Is there a list of ID’s for all the buttons in the toolbar somewhere, so that I can hide the ones I want don’t want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the list of Ajax File Browser toolbar buttons IDs:

- ViewsButton
- FoldersButton
- UpButton
- RefreshButton
- UploadButton
- UploadFolderButton
- NewFolderButton
- DownloadButton
- EditButton
- FileManagerButton
- VersionsButton
- CustomPropButton
- DeleteButton
- CopyButton
- CutButton
- PasteButton
- InfoButton

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

JQUERY:

```
$.ajax({
  type: '[POST] Or[GET]',
  url: '[URL]',
  data: '[data]'
}).done(function(data){
   //do something
});
```

Handler:

```
<?
if ([file] == 'map')
{
  //do something
}
else
{
  //do something
}
?>
```

Put the handler in an other .php file!